Using Kuratowski embedding
I was wondering if one can use the Kuratowski embedding theorem in the following way:
suppose $X$ is a locally convex metrizable and complete topological vector space (LCMCTVS), then there is an isometric isomorphism such that $X$ embeds in $L^{\infty}(X)$ (Banach space of bounded functions on X with sup-norm). Since $X$ is complete the image of the isometric isomorphism is complete hence closed in $L^{\infty}(X)$, thus being a closed of a Banach space (I think the delicate point is here since it’s not necessarily a subspace). If what I've said is correct then could I use this fact to prove facts about operators between LCMCTVS using already known facts about Banach spaces? For example to prove the fact that an operator from a Banach to itself has nonempty spectrum.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

The Kuratowski embedding theorem works for any metric space and, as such, it ignores the linear structure of a metrisable TVS $X$ if one applies this theorem to $X$. Indeed, it has to as otherwise you would prove that every metrisable TVS is normable, which is false, e.g. take $X = \ell_p$ for $p\in (0,1)$ (you try to argue it is a subspace of a Banach space).
PS. There exist continuous operators on Fréchet spaces with empty spectra; see

M. Landsberg, Pseudonormen in der Theorie der linearen topologischen Räume. Math. Nachr. 14 (1955), 29-38.
A. L. Shields, The Spectrum of an operator on an F-space, Proc. Roy. Irish Acad. Sect. A 74. (1974), 291-292.


Thanks, I had realized this since it sounded too beautiful to be true. I was trying to solve the problem about the spectrum of an operator between metrizable and complete TVSs and I thought I could translate the problem in the already known Banach case, any suggestion on how I could cope with it?

@Alessandro, I think it is possible to cook up a complex metrisable TVS and an operator on it with an empty spectrum. I am not an expert beyond the normed case though.

even though the space is complete? any suggestion on how to "cook" it?. I've been thinking something using a simple space like $C(R)$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets but didn't come up with any idea

@Alessandro, please see the references above.
